# How to set valid datetime-local for WINDOWS 10 browsers

Tags: html, datetime

When running in windows mm/dd/yyyy is displayed but in Windows dd/mm/yyyy format is displayed. Is that bug or any solution is available for that problem.

```
<html>
    <body>
        DATE AND TIME
        <input type="datetime-local" id="time1"></input>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Isn't that just down the user's preferences for how they want dates displayed on their system?

Comment: but also in windows 10 it only displayed in 24 hours format and other systems it shows 12 hours format

Comment: Again, that sounds more like the preferences for that partiular system being set that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is depending upon the local system time